# Getview with Gridview depending on Asynctasks result

Tags: android, performance, gridview, android-asynctask, smooth-scrolling

I have some performance in my Android application. I have a Gridview with 4 columns, displaying at a time 8 items. The number of items that my database contains it's around 14000, so when I scroll until my offset (200 items) I read from the DB another 200 items and discard the previous 200.
These items contain a lot of information, like stock, price, added items to cart, the total price of added items to cart, bitmaps, etc.
In the Getview method I can load some of this information, but a lot of it I need to read it from the local database, and because of that, I created a Asynctask that I run inside the getView method. The problem is that I pass the viewholder to the asynctask and in the onPostExecute method I set the values to the viewholder and that forces the Getview method to be called over and over again, resulting in performance issues.

I also tried to add to the item that I store in the adapter a flag "isFullyLoaded" and checked in the Getview if the ifFullyLoaded was true, if it was I passed all the code of onPostExecute from the AsyncTask to this condition, otherwise, it would just call the AsyncTask and in the onPostExecute it sets the "isFullyLoaded" to false. But here its another problem, because it will use the recycled view, resulting in inconsistent information.

I am looking for tips on how should I do this to improve performance while scrolling.